# How to call super().super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's convenient for us to call `__init__()` from a child class via `super().__init__()`, but what should I do when I want to call `__init__()` from a grandchild? For example:

```
class A(Base):
     def __init__(self):
         ...
class B(A):
     def __init__(self):
         ...
class C(B):
     def __init__(self):
        ...
```

So how to call `A.__init__()` inside `C.__init__()` **without** calling `B.__init__()`? Apparantly, you can include `super().__init__()` inside both `B.__init__()` and `C.__init__()`. But due to some special reason, I need to avoid calling `B.__init__()` (i.e., calling `super().__init__()` inside `C.__init__()`), then what should I do?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to bypass the parent? This seems like incredibly poor design.

Comment: According to the python logic of inheritance you shouldn't want to do so.

Comment: In other words, if you find yourself needing to do this, there's likely something wrong with the design of your classes.

Comment: Maybe make a `def specialInitForCToCall:` in A and call that from C?

Comment: `super()` isn't even necessarily the parent when there is multiple inheritance. If you need to refer to a specific class, you can just name it.

Comment: You can call `A.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so simple. You just need to call `A.__init__(self)` in `C` class constructor.
for example, assume that A class is:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('a')
```

And B class, implements A class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('b')
```

Then you can implement C class like this:

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print('c')
```

So the outputs will be:

`In[1]: obj1 = A()`

```
a
```

`In[2]: obj2 = B()`

```
a
b
```

`In[3]: obj3 = C()`

```
a
c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call the upper class' **init** function directly:

```
class C(B):
     def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        ...
```

However, the whole idea of skipping a class in the hierarchy is bound to cause issues in the future.

Depending on the reason that is leading you to want this, you could:

- add a parameter to your **init** function to control the behaviour in class B when called from the constructor of A.
- make C a subclass of A and place common code in a separate class that you add using multiple inheritance.
- place B's initialization code in a separate function that you override in C to make it do nothing